# I want to upload an image via a yii2 api

Tags: php, api, yii2

I am working on project that requires uploading/updating an profile image through an api from a mobile device.
I create a method to upload an image and test with postman but it returns `UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('photo')` null , Please what am i doing wrong?
Below is my code:
Usercontroller

```
public function actionUpload()
{

    $userid = Yii::$app->request->get('id');
    $photo = $_FILES['photo'];

    $model = Users::findOne($userid);

    if($model === null){
        Authorization::badRequest($model,true);
        return;
    //}
       // return $_FILES;

    // return $model->upload();
   // $model->save();
   // if($model->upload()){

     // return array('token'=>$model->getJwt());
    }else {
        $model->photo = UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('photo');
      return $model->photo;
    }
}

Model
public function upload()
{
  if ($this->validate()) {
      $this->photo->saveAs(self::IMG_PATH . $this->photo->baseName . '.' . $this->photo->extension);
        return true;

  }else {
    return false;
  }

}
```

Comment: What verb are you using for that method ? is it post or put ?

Comment: post verb @sobhanbagheri

Comment: check the `$_FILES` value to make sure the file exists and the name "photo" you have put in `getInstanceByName()` is correct

Answer (score 0):

I upload pic without ( upload function )

```js
$model->file = uploadedfile::getInstance($model,'file');
                
$model->file->saveAs( 'uploads/'.$model->file>basename.'.'.$model->file->extension);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. The issue is when i test with postman,  this line : $model->file = uploadedfile::getInstance($model,'file');  returns null,

Comment: how about your _from do you used 'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'